# Binding TabControl.ItemsSource to ViewModels whose View's are a TabItem

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I need some `TabItem`s to have a customized `Header`.
For example, given the following (working) XAML:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <Button>Header 1</Button>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <Label>Content 1</Label>
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <Label>Header 2</Label>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock>Content 2</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

I would like to extract the tab items into their own Views + ViewModels. The `TabItem`'s View should still be a `TabItem`, so that I can configure the `Header` per tab item instead of setting `TabControl.ItemTemplate` and using a `DataTemplateSelector` to achieve different headers per tab item.

At the same time I'd need to be able to bind the selected tab item view model to a property `ActiveItem`. => The underlying view-model for the TabControl is a `Conductor.Collection.OneActive<T>` (only the selected tab should be activated).

If there's an alternative to using `TabItem` as view-type, but still achieving the `Header` and `Content` to be specified in the same view, it would be acceptable, too.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve this by binding a `TabControlViewModel` to the `TabControl`, and that VM should have an `ObservableCollection` of `TabViewModel`s (maybe a base class or interface).  You would bind your collection of `TabViewModel`s to the `TabControl`'s `ItemsSource`.  Here is my implementation, but using the Telerik `TabControl` (should be same for MS):

```
<telerik:RadTabControl x:Name="RadTabControl"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Align="Justify"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource LoggerDataTemplateSelector}"
                        IsContentPreserved="True"
                        IsDefaultItemSelected="True"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding LogHistory}"
                        SupressSelectedContentTemplateReapplying="False">
    <telerik:RadTabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <!-- Allow IsSelected to be bound to view models-->
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource RadTabItemStyle}"
                TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTabItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </Style>
    </telerik:RadTabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <telerik:RadTabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- Define what is shown in the header -->
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="30">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Text="{Binding Title}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadTabControl.ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadTabControl>
```

Be aware, MS doesn't have something like `IsContentPreserved`, so switching tabs that have a lot of data to show will be rather timely.  There are also a couple other properties not in MS `TabControl`, however the important properties should all be there.  In this case, your `TabViewModel` should have a `IsSelected` property and `Title` property.

Comment: as stated in the question I'm specifically looking for a solution not involving either a fixed `DataTemplate` for the header (which you did by specifying `RadTabControl.ItemTemplate`) nor a `DataTemplateSelector`. I already now how to bind my viewmodels + specific views as items of a `TabControl`. What i would like to achieve is specifying a custom header and content both in one XAML node (hence `TabItem` which includes exactly that) which should be per view model.

Comment: Also i don't need an `IsSelected` property on each tab item view model, rather I'm fine with only the container-ViewModel (the one of the `TabControl`) knowing which is the selected one (it can be done). I only included this requirement because applying an `IValueConverter` to the item source to convert the ViewModels to `TabItems` (with it's corresponding ViewModel as `DataContext`) is possible but makes conversion in the other direction (which is the selected view model?) a bit more complicated as well.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, though.

Comment: This sounds impossible to do with MVVM if you don't use a ItemTemplateSelector.  You'd have to store the UI elements in the VM otherwise.

Comment: With caliburn.micro, one often does something like this: `<ContentControl cal:View.Model={Binding SelectedItem}/>` and automagically the view of the bound view model appears. That's a bit simpler though because it wraps the view in a `ContentControl`, whereas here I would require the view not to be wrapped but added directly as a child. After some fiddling i found some working solutions but i'm not quite happy with them (too complicated). I'll post them tomorrow for a reference, maybe someone knows something simpler / better.

Comment: As a matter of fact the only way to have "dynamic views" is using TemplateSelectors.  You're need to edit the style of TabItem and make use of its HeaderTemplateSelector and ContentTemplateSelector to do what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89969/discussion-between-batterybackupunit-and-netscape).

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit I am wondering how did you manage to insert specific instance of TabItem (which you define in XAML) into TabControl while binding to TabControl.ItemsSource?

Comment: @Stipo there are several alterantives: a) use a converter on `ItemSource` which converts the bound view models to their corresponding views (which need to be `TabItem`s), b) use attached properties to do the conversion c) use a intermediate collection / view model which converts viewmodels to views and back (for SelectedItem...)

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit Thanks for answer! But it seems to me that using TabControl.ItemContainerStyle, TabItem.HeaderTemplateSelector and TabItem.ContentTemplateSelector is cleaner and perhaps even easier.

Comment: @Stipo well the disadvantage is that every time you add a new type of child with a different layout, you'll need to adapt the `TabControl`. Which is not very nice in terms of separation of concerns. However, i agree that circumventing this means a lot of extra work and in most instances it's not going to be worth it, at all.